# ajax post double triggers each time sending form

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

i working with asp.net mvc5 and trying to post a form to the controller without refreshing the page using ajax. but the problem is that each time i press the submit button, it sends the data many times. only the first time it submits the form once. but the second time it send twice, and the third time it sends four times and ...

here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UniProject.Models;

namespace UniProject.Controllers
{
  public class TestController : Controller
    {
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    // GET: Test
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Test test)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tests.Add(test);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Record = "Data Inserted";
                return PartialView("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Record = "Error";
                return View(test);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Record = "Error";
            return View();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

this is my view

```
@model UniProject.Models.Test

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="div">
    @Html.Partial("Form" , Model)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My PartialView

```
@model UniProject.Models.Test

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create" , "Test" , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod =    "post" , UpdateTargetId = "div"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Test</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

this the form view after once clicking submit button
[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnMHZ.jpg)

and this is the database image
[Database Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck4Ag.jpg)

please help me with this issue. thanks in advance...

Comment: Your returning the full view  (which is why you see the "Index" heading twice) and are therefore including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` twice. The controller method needs to return just the partial - `return PartialView("Form");` although its unclear why you are returning the view if `ModelState` is valid - you should be redirecting.

Comment: thank you so much your instruction worked for me. but the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is just included once.

Comment: No its not - its in the `Index` view initially, then you load it again (because you returning the `Index` view again in the controller method) And if you submit again, 3 copies will be loaded etc.

Comment: i am new to asp.net. and one more thing please. what should the create method return in general?

Comment: am i doing right at all or not?

Comment: Its a bit unclear even why your using `Ajax.BeginForm()` for this. Why are you wanting to stay on the same page after you have created the object? Why not a normal submit that redirects to another view (of is `ModelState` is invalid, return the view so the user can correct it. Even if you do want the user to keep creating multiple objects, then all you should be doing is returning a value indicating success or otherwise, and clear the reset the form values.

Comment: And I recommend you use the jQuery.Ajax()` methods rather than `Ajax.BeginForm()` - you get far better controls (and `Ajax.BeginForm()` is not even supported in the latest version of MVC

Comment: And why is your GET method named `Index` when its only purpose is to 'Create' and object. It should be named `Create()` and the view can include the form (a partial is not necessary)